# Protecting app from decompiling by hiding Manifest and converting code to Unicode character

Tags: java, android, unicode, android-manifest, decompiling

> I want to make my app protective by using obfuscation or any good technique like i am showing. I have gone through a number of questions on SO.

**While decompiling I see two good technique.**

1. An app hides  `Androidmanifest.xml`  as i decompiled a code and it's Manifest.xml is missing or not there.
2. And another code i seen it after decompiled as given below.

   ```
   private static void \u02ca(final Context context, String s, final String s2) 
   {
   if (s == null || s.equals("")) 
   {
       return;
   }
   final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
   final boolean \u02cf = \u0632.\u02cf(context);

   if (!\u02cf || (\u02cf && !\u0632.\u02ce(context))) 
   {
       if (s == null) 
       {
           s = null;
       }
       \u02ca(context, s);
   }
   while (true) 
   {
       if (s2 == null || s2.equals("")) 
       {
           break Label_0076;
       }
       try 
       {
           Toast.makeText(context, (CharSequence)s2, 1).show();
           \u0632.\u02ca(context, "letang_last_time", currentTimeMillis);
       }
       catch (Exception ex) {
           continue;
       }
       break;
   }
   }
   ```

May be anyone understand what this example is using to protect the apk from decompiling.

**How to make my code in UniCode like character after decompiling? And how to hide Manifest from Decompiling.**

**Edit**

I have tested in on three different decompilers.but the code remain the same. None of  `Procyon,CFR,FernFlower` help to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make my code in UniCode like character after decompiling? And
>   how to hide Manifest from Decompiling.

Keep in mind that there is no 100% protection. You can add simple ways which make it more difficult for the potential attacker but there is no safe harbor in this environment. There is an open source tool from Google called [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#android). It also helps you to obfuscate your source code.

> - Creating more compact code, for smaller code archives, faster    transfer across networks, faster loading, and smaller memory footprints.
> - Making programs and libraries harder to reverse-engineer.
> - Listing dead code, so it can be removed from the source code.
> - Retargeting and preverifying existing class files for Java 6 or    higher, to take full advantage of their faster class loading.

Answer (score 0):

> An app hides  Androidmanifest.xml as i decompiled a code and it's
>   Manifest.xml is missing or not there.

I test this as I was learning how to use proguard. Actually it turned out that even if you manage to retrieve the AndroidManifeste.xml file, it is empty. I tested this on several APK the xml is empty

As for your second question, I would suggest that you test the APK that has this sort of Unicode, and decompile it using AndroChef decompiler. AndroChef always retrieves the JAVA code from most APKs even if using proguard.